# Android Location DistanceTo null

Tags: java, android, gps, location

```
package com.competitivegamingaudio;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.*;
import com.google.android.maps.*;;

public class FindMyFriendsActivity extends Activity {


private static final String TAG = "FindMyFriendsActivity";
public TextView LocationLabel;
public TextView DistanceLabel;
public MapView myMapView;
public Location oldlocation;
public Location currentlocation;

@Override
public void onResume()
    {
    super.onResume();
    LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LocationLabel=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.LocationLabel);
    DistanceLabel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.DistanceLabel);



}

LocationListener locationListener =new LocationListener()
{
public void onLocationChanged (Location location)
    {
    currentlocation=new Location(location);
    LocationLabel.setText(location.toString());
    oldlocation=new Location(location);
    DistanceLabel.setText("Distance: "+calculatedistance(currentlocation,oldlocation));

    }
public String calculatedistance(Location a, Location b)
    {
    a.distanceTo(b);
    return ""+a;
    }
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {

    }
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
{}

};

}
```

I'm having trouble getting this code to work properly. I want to be able to calculate the distance between two Locations. The initial location that's being passed to the onLocationChanged method is working (which proves I have the right conditions), because when I do `LocationLabel.setText(location.toString());` that works properly without getting any null pointer exceptions. However, when the `calculatedistance` method is called in line 49, the `a.distanceTo(b);` line fails on line 54. Any idea why the distanceTo method keeps failing?

Error Message:

```
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.competitivegamingaudio.FindMyFriendsActivity$1.onLocationChanged(FindMyFriendsActivity.java:47)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:227)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:176)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-09 20:11:58.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/LocationLabel"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/> 
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/DistanceLabel"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your code oldlocation and currentlocation is the same??

Comment: Post your logcat showing the exception

Comment: 01-09 18:42:06.342: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 18:42:06.342: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7891): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 18:42:06.342: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7891):     at com.competitivegamingaudio.FindMyFriendsActivity$1.onLocationChanged(FindMyFriendsActivity.java:49)
01-09 18:42:06.342: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7891):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:227)
etc...

Comment: oldlocation and currentlocation are the same intentionally. Originally I was using the latitude and longitude of the White House for the old location, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by copying DistanceLabel from my Java code and pasting it over the similar DistanceLabel in main.xml. All the characters appear the same but it fixed it. Perhaps looking at it in a hex editor would help but for now I'm just glad it's working. Thanks MisterSquonk.

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are a lot of things I'd change about your code but here's not the place. To attempt to fix your problem try this...

```
// package and imports here

public class FindMyFriendsActivity extends Activity {

    // TAG, TextViews, MapView, Locations as before but add
    // LocationManager and LocationListener here as below...
    LocationManager locationManager = null;
    LocationListener locationListener = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocationLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LocationLabel);
        DistanceLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DistanceLabel);

        locationManager=(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            // Put LocationListener methods here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that didn't work. the problem isn't that the locationManager or locationListener is null (they're not). It's telling me that oldlocation is null.

Comment: The problem is when you posted the logcat you only posted a few lines and finished with 'etc' which REALLY doesn't help. Post the bit that shows 'Caused by'

Comment: If I comment out `DistanceLabel.setText("Distance: "+calculatedistance(currentlocation,oldlocation));` then the program runs just fine. But still doesn't help me with the whole getting the distance between two locations thing.

Comment: As I said above, post the complete logcat exception including the 'Caused by' part as an edit to your question.

Comment: There is no "caused by" clause. Which is weird, because I have seen it before when I've run into other errors.

Comment: And you definitely have a `TextView` in `main.xml` which has the id `DistanceLabel`? (case sensitive)

Comment: Hmm when I tried to do `DistanceLabel.setText("Hello World");` got the null pointer exception too. I've edited my question to include main.xml but it looks correct to me. The ID appears to be set properly so I'm not sure why that's not hooking up properly.

Comment: Solved by copying DistanceLabel from my Java code and pasting it over the similar DistanceLabel in main.xml. All the characters appear the same but it fixed it. Perhaps looking at it in a hex editor would help but for now I'm just glad it's working. I'd mark this as the answer, but I'm a new user so it won't let me yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, I was going to suggest running "Project -> Clean" assuming you're using eclipse. Best guess is the ID had got out of sync. BTW, you accept the answer by clicking the "check" icon below the vote count. It should let you do it even as a new user (I think). Anyway, glad it's sorted. Good luck.